# Time series with irregular time step as test data for machine learning regression tool

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, forecasting, openweathermap

I have developed a machine learning regression tool for energy forecasting where as a test set I need data from a weather API. This weather API gives me values with different time steps, minute values for an hour, hourly values for 48 hours and daily values for 7 days. I want that my forecast also gives me the results for those time frames but of course, since it is energy, the results vary if it is minute, hour or daily values.

Does anyone have experience on how to deal with **time series with irregular time step as test set**? Would I have to train my model at each time step to have a forecast also in minute, hour and daily values?

Info about the weather API: https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api

Comment: In my opinion, as you don't have access to minute values for several weeks which would have enabled you to use only one dataset to create several model depending on your forecasting needs, you'll have to create 3 models using your 3 different datasets. This question would better fit in https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Use the facebook prophet model for time series forecasting , use its function makeprediction(set time duration) and it will help you with the prediction as per your need .